# Why no singly linked list in Rust official library?

Tags: list, rust

Rust official libraries contain [doubly linked list](http://doc.rust-lang.org/0.11.0/collections/dlist/struct.DList.html). But no singly linked one. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presumably because nobody bothered to write one. As for why nobody did that...

There's already a doubly linked list. The *only* tangible advantage of a singly linked list is using one less pointer per node, which isn't all that much. If space usage is important, you'd probably use a `Vec` or a similar data structure. The over-allocation of `Vec` is balanced by the per-node overhead (pointers as well as allocator overhead), especially for small items (ints, pointers, and the like).

Also, linked lists in general are not as useful as one might think after CS 102, `Vec` and the like are often a better choice. The few operations which are asymptotically faster are relatively rare, for everything that's asymptotically equal they lose due to data locality, and even the asymptotically faster operations need astonishingly large n to overtake the data locality disadvantage.

Comment: Singly linked lists implemented with some sort of multiply owned pointer type do allow for persistence/sharing of the tail like Haskell.

Comment: @dbaupp Good point. I was thinking imperatively again.